# Create virtual field in constructor from an existing field

Tags: php, sql, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have this model called `Product`

```
class Product extends AppModel {

    public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {
        parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

        $file_name = (preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $this->field('product_picture')));
        $ext = end((explode(".", $this->field('product_picture')))); # extra () to prevent notice
        $this->virtualFields['product_picture_thumbnail'] = $file_name."350x350.".$ext;
    }
}
```

It has a field called `product_picture` which is something like **img1.png**. I want to create a virtual field that's created based on that name, which stands for something like **img1350x350.png**.

So when I query, it returns an empty list.

```
$this->Product->find('all', array(
    'fields' => array(
        'product_picture', 
        'product_picture_thumbnail', 
)));
```

Comment: I was wondering if you managed to try my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing PHP code with SQL code. Virtual fields will only work if they can be parsed by the database.

In case you are using MySQL, the following should work:

```
public function __construct($id = false, $table = null, $ds = null) {

    parent::__construct($id, $table, $ds);

    $this->virtualFields['product_picture_thumbnail'] = sprintf('
        CONCAT(
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(%s.product_picture,".",1),
            "350x350.",
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(%s.product_picture,".",-1)
        )',
        $this->alias, $this->alias) ;
}
```

I've included code to dyamically generate the model name, so that it also works with aliases, as described in [CakePHP 2.x: Virtual fields and model aliases](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html#virtual-fields-and-model-aliases).